# Find out test body from within a listener method?

Tags: robotframework

Is there a way to determine the "body" of the current test from within a listener object?  Specifically, the text that makes up the test itself?  So, for example, can I in end_test determine the body of the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `start_suite` and `end_suite` methods of a listener include the absolute path to the file. You can open the file and read it to get the source. There is no way to get the body of just a single test, though you could use the robot parser to parse the source, and from that you can drill into the objects to find the steps for the current test.

For future reference, there's a long-standing enhancement request to send more data to the listeners. This would give you what you need, but it doesn't look like it's going to get implemented anytime soon.

https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/1208

Your other option is the to capture every keyword start and append it to a list if it's an immediate child of a testcase. Each time you get a test start, reset the list.